# How can I concatenate csv colums and rename their header with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to merge two csv files together and select only two of their columns for use in a new csv. I don't understand why I cannot use the code I have already:

```
$Temp1 = (Import-csv "C:\path\APPcsv.csv" -header "APP") | 
    select-object APP
$Temp2 = (Import-csv "C:\path\ALLdb42APPs.csv"-header "NA1", "NA2", "Applications", "NA3", "Project") | 
    select-object Project

$CSV= @($temp1, $temp2) | 
    export-csv -path "C:\path\Why isn't this working.csv" -noTypeInformation
```

Here is an example line from each CSV:

CSV1 (ALLdb42APPs.csv)

```
"Current Application","Calculation","AdobeReaderDC-18.011.20036 V1 - Add  Instalation Status: SUCCESSFUL","2018-05-16 08:54:17","DK ATM error main"
```

CSV2 (APPcsv.csv)

```
"DameWareService-10.0.0.0-x64 V2 - Add"
```

Comment: `Join-Object` would be my goto if there was a common field... could you include a few example lines from each csv so we can see what data you're working with.

Comment: So there's no commonality between the CSV lines? AdobeReader & DameWare don't seem linked in any way?

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is because `@($temp1,$temp2)` doesn't combine the first element of `$temp1` with the first element of `$temp2`, but instead makes a new collection which is all of `$temp1`'s objects followed by all of `$temp2`.

Since `$temp1` is objects with an `APP` property and `$temp2` is objects with a `Project`, combining these into a collection doesn't make sense to export to a csv.

If `$temp1` is a bag of apples and `$temp2` is a bag of oranges, `@($temp1,$temp2)` isn't holding the bags together, it's dumping both into one bag on top of each other.

You could either join the two objects into one. Warren Frame has a well respected module [Join-Object](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) that could be used as James C pointed out, but your two csvs would need to share a column.

The other alternative is to use a for loop, then in each iteration take the value from each collection and create a new object with both values.

```
$Temp1 = (Import-csv "C:\path\APPcsv.csv" -header "APP") | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty APP
$Temp2 = (Import-csv "C:\path\ALLdb42APPs.csv"-header "NA1", "NA2", "Applications", "NA3", "Project") | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Project

$LargestIndex = [math]::Max($temp1.count,$temp2.count)

$CombinedArray = For ($i=0; $i -le $LargestIndex; $i++) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        APP = $temp1[$i]
        Project = $temp2[$i]
    }
}

$CombinedArray | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\path\Example.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: requires PowerShell 3+ for the pscustomobject way of creating objects.

Comment: Thank you. I spent quite some time trying multiple avenues for achieving my goal, not quite understanding what I was missing. You've helped greatly.